# How to edit HTML text again when a toggle is switched with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first time ever working with HTML and Javascript, so help would be very appreciated!
I'm attempting to create a Dark Mode toggle, and it works! When I toggle the switch, the background changes to black, and when I switch it again, it goes back to white. However, I want to add a little piece of text telling the user if Dark Mode is On or Off. I got it to work with this line of code:

```
function myFunction() {
   var element = document.body;
   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
   document.getElementById("switchlabel").innerHTML = "Night: On";
```

And when I switch the toggle, the text changes from "Night: Off" to "Night: On", exactly as I needed it to.
Problem is, I need it to then switch back to "Night: Off" when the toggle is set to off.
Does anyone know how to do that? I've tried looking it up but found no answers.

Comment: ```document.getElementById("switchlabel").innerHTML = element.classList.contains("dark-mode")?"Night: On":"Night: Off";``` this should do the trick

Comment: @ikhvjs Thanks! I edited the text and it does change!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct but for changing `innerHTML` you should change it conditionally based on `body` class.

I used value returned from `classList.toggle` to determine `dark-mode` class is present or not and thus based on that boolean value, `innerHTML` would be changed.

```js
function myFunction() {
   var element = document.body;
   var darkMode = element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
   document.getElementById("switchlabel").innerHTML = darkMode ? 'ON' : 'OFF'
}
```

```css
body.dark-mode {
  background: #b1b1b1
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Night: </span>
  <label id="switchlabel">OFF</label> 
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Toggle Mode</button>
```